# how to set custom image on space between two CirclePageIndicator in android?

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I am used viewpager and also to used custom library CirclePageIndicator and problem is that image draw on select and unselect with space between two circle image draw and but select and unselect image draw and image not draw space between two image, please be help me

Actual ouput i need to and snapshot,
[image]

Device output as,
[image]

My CirclePageIndicator class as,

```
public class CirclePageIndicator extends View implements PageIndicator {

    private static final int INVALID_POINTER = -1;

    private float mRadius;
    private final Paint mPaintPageFill = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private final Paint mPaintStroke = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private final Paint mPaintFill = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mListener;
    private int mCurrentPage;
    private int mSnapPage;
    private float mPageOffset;
    private int mScrollState;
    private int mOrientation;
    private boolean mCentered;
    private boolean mSnap;

    private int mTouchSlop;
    private float mLastMotionX = -1;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER;
    private boolean mIsDragging;

    public CirclePageIndicator(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CirclePageIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CirclePageIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        if (isInEditMode()) return;

        //Load defaults from resources
        final Resources res = getResources();
        final int defaultPageColor = res.getColor(R.color.default_circle_indicator_page_color);
        final int defaultFillColor = res.getColor(R.color.default_circle_indicator_fill_color);
        final int defaultOrientation = res.getInteger(R.integer.default_circle_indicator_orientation);
        final int defaultStrokeColor = res.getColor(R.color.default_circle_indicator_stroke_color);
        final float defaultStrokeWidth = res.getDimension(R.dimen.default_circle_indicator_stroke_width);
        final float defaultRadius = res.getDimension(R.dimen.default_circle_indicator_radius);
        final boolean defaultCentered = res.getBoolean(R.bool.default_circle_indicator_centered);
        final boolean defaultSnap = res.getBoolean(R.bool.default_circle_indicator_snap);

        // Retrieve styles attributes
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator, defStyle, 0);

        mCentered = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator_centered, defaultCentered);
        mOrientation = a.getInt(R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator_android_orientation, defaultOrientation);
        mPaintPageFill.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        mPaintPageFill.setColor(a.getColor(R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator_pageColor, defaultPageColor));
        mPaintStroke.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        mPaintStroke.setColor(a.getColor(R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator_strokeColor, defaultStrokeColor));
        mPaintStroke.setStrokeWidth(a.getDimension(R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator_strokeWidth, defaultStrokeWidth));
        mPaintFill.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        mPaintFill.setColor(a.getColor(R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator_fillColor, defaultFillColor));
        mRadius = a.getDimension(R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator_radius, defaultRadius);
        mSnap = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator_snap, defaultSnap);

        Drawable background = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator_android_background);
        if (background != null) {
            setBackgroundDrawable(background);
        }

        a.recycle();

        final ViewConfiguration configuration = ViewConfiguration.get(context);
        mTouchSlop = ViewConfigurationCompat.getScaledPagingTouchSlop(configuration);
    }


    public void setCentered(boolean centered) {
        mCentered = centered;
        invalidate();
    }

    public boolean isCentered() {
        return mCentered;
    }

    public void setPageColor(int pageColor) {
        mPaintPageFill.setColor(pageColor);
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getPageColor() {
        return mPaintPageFill.getColor();
    }

    public void setFillColor(int fillColor) {
        mPaintFill.setColor(fillColor);
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getFillColor() {
        return mPaintFill.getColor();
    }

    public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
        switch (orientation) {
            case HORIZONTAL:
            case VERTICAL:
                mOrientation = orientation;
                requestLayout();
                break;

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Orientation must be either HORIZONTAL or VERTICAL.");
        }
    }

    public int getOrientation() {
        return mOrientation;
    }

    public void setStrokeColor(int strokeColor) {
        mPaintStroke.setColor(strokeColor);
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getStrokeColor() {
        return mPaintStroke.getColor();
    }

    public void setStrokeWidth(float strokeWidth) {
        mPaintStroke.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        invalidate();
    }

    public float getStrokeWidth() {
        return mPaintStroke.getStrokeWidth();
    }

    public void setRadius(float radius) {
        mRadius = radius;
        invalidate();
    }

    public float getRadius() {
        return mRadius;
    }

    public void setSnap(boolean snap) {
        mSnap = snap;
        invalidate();
    }

    public boolean isSnap() {
        return mSnap;
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (mViewPager == null) {
            return;
        }

        final int count = mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount();
        if (count == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if (mCurrentPage >= count) {
            setCurrentItem(count - 1);
            return;
        }

        int longSize;
        int longPaddingBefore;
        int longPaddingAfter;
        int shortPaddingBefore;
        if (mOrientation == HORIZONTAL) {
            longSize = getWidth();
            longPaddingBefore = getPaddingLeft();
            longPaddingAfter = getPaddingRight();
            shortPaddingBefore = getPaddingTop();
        } else {
            longSize = getHeight();
            longPaddingBefore = getPaddingTop();
            longPaddingAfter = getPaddingBottom();
            shortPaddingBefore = getPaddingLeft();
        }

        final float threeRadius = mRadius * 3;
        final float shortOffset = shortPaddingBefore + mRadius;
        float longOffset = longPaddingBefore + mRadius;
        if (mCentered) {
            longOffset += ((longSize - longPaddingBefore - longPaddingAfter) / 2.0f) - ((count * threeRadius) / 2.0f);
        }

        float dX = 0.0f;
        float dY = 0.0f;

        float pageFillRadius = mRadius;
        if (mPaintStroke.getStrokeWidth() > 0) {
            pageFillRadius -= mPaintStroke.getStrokeWidth() / 2.0f;
        }

        //Draw stroked circles
        for (int iLoop = 0; iLoop < count; iLoop++) {
            float drawLong = longOffset + (iLoop * threeRadius);
            if (mOrientation == HORIZONTAL) {
                dX = drawLong;
                dY = shortOffset;
            } else {
                dX = shortOffset;
                dY = drawLong;
            }
            // Only paint fill if not completely transparent
            if (mPaintPageFill.getAlpha() > 0) {
                canvas.drawCircle(dX, dY, pageFillRadius, mPaintPageFill);
//              Bitmap mBitmapLine = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.slider_line);
//                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapLine, dX, dY, mPaintPageFill);
            }

            // Only paint stroke if a stroke width was non-zero
            if (pageFillRadius != mRadius) {
//                canvas.drawCircle(dX, dY, mRadius, mPaintStroke);
                Bitmap mBitmapCircleNormal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.slider_circle_normal);
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapCircleNormal, dX, dY, mPaintStroke);
            }
        }

        // Draw the filled circle according to the current scroll
        float cx = (mSnap ? mSnapPage : mCurrentPage) * threeRadius;
        if (!mSnap) {
            cx += mPageOffset * threeRadius;
        }

        if (mOrientation == HORIZONTAL) {
            dX = longOffset + cx;
            dY = shortOffset;
        } else {
            dX = shortOffset;
            dY = longOffset + cx;
        }

//        System.out.println("cx === "+cx);
//        Bitmap mBitmapLine = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.slider_line);
//        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapLine, dX, dY, mPaintFill);  

//      canvas.drawCircle(dX, dY, mRadius, mPaintFill);
        Bitmap mBitmapCircleHover = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.slider_circle_hover);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapCircleHover, dX, dY, mPaintFill);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent ev) {
        if (super.onTouchEvent(ev)) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((mViewPager == null) || (mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount() == 0)) {
            return false;
        }

        final int action = ev.getAction() & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK;
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, 0);
                mLastMotionX = ev.getX();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                final int activePointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(ev, mActivePointerId);
                final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, activePointerIndex);
                final float deltaX = x - mLastMotionX;

                if (!mIsDragging) {
                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mTouchSlop) {
                        mIsDragging = true;
                    }
                }

                if (mIsDragging) {
                    mLastMotionX = x;
                    if (mViewPager.isFakeDragging() || mViewPager.beginFakeDrag()) {
                        mViewPager.fakeDragBy(deltaX);
                    }
                }

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (!mIsDragging) {
                    final int count = mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount();
                    final int width = getWidth();
                    final float halfWidth = width / 2f;
                    final float sixthWidth = width / 6f;

                    if ((mCurrentPage > 0) && (ev.getX() < halfWidth - sixthWidth)) {
                        if (action != MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mCurrentPage - 1);
                        }
                        return true;
                    } else if ((mCurrentPage < count - 1) && (ev.getX() > halfWidth + sixthWidth)) {
                        if (action != MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mCurrentPage + 1);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                mIsDragging = false;
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER;
                if (mViewPager.isFakeDragging()) mViewPager.endFakeDrag();
                break;

            case MotionEventCompat.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
                final int index = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(ev);
                mLastMotionX = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, index);
                mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, index);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEventCompat.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(ev);
                final int pointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, pointerIndex);
                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, newPointerIndex);
                }
                mLastMotionX = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(ev, mActivePointerId));
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setViewPager(ViewPager view) {
        if (mViewPager == view) {
            return;
        }

        if (mViewPager != null) {
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(null);
        }

        if (view.getAdapter() == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ViewPager does not have adapter instance.");
        }

        mViewPager = view;
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void setViewPager(ViewPager view, int initialPosition) {
        setViewPager(view);
        setCurrentItem(initialPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCurrentItem(int item) {
        if (mViewPager == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ViewPager has not been bound.");
        }
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(item);
        mCurrentPage = item;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        mScrollState = state;
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        mCurrentPage = position;
        mPageOffset = positionOffset;
        invalidate();

        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (mSnap || mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mCurrentPage = position;
            mSnapPage = position;
            invalidate();
        }

        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onPageSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see android.view.View#onMeasure(int, int)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (mOrientation == HORIZONTAL) {
            setMeasuredDimension(measureLong(widthMeasureSpec), measureShort(heightMeasureSpec));
        } else {
            setMeasuredDimension(measureShort(widthMeasureSpec), measureLong(heightMeasureSpec));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determines the width of this view
     *
     * @param measureSpec
     *            A measureSpec packed into an int
     * @return The width of the view, honoring constraints from measureSpec
     */
    private int measureLong(int measureSpec) {
        int result;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if ((specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) || (mViewPager == null)) {
            //We were told how big to be
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            //Calculate the width according the views count
            final int count = mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount();
            result = (int)(getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight()
                    + (count * 2 * mRadius) + (count - 1) * mRadius + 1);
            //Respect AT_MOST value if that was what is called for by measureSpec
            if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                result = Math.min(result, specSize);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Determines the height of this view
     *
     * @param measureSpec
     *            A measureSpec packed into an int
     * @return The height of the view, honoring constraints from measureSpec
     */
    private int measureShort(int measureSpec) {
        int result;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            //We were told how big to be
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            //Measure the height
            result = (int)(2 * mRadius + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom() + 1);
            //Respect AT_MOST value if that was what is called for by measureSpec
            if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                result = Math.min(result, specSize);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        SavedState savedState = (SavedState)state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState.getSuperState());
        mCurrentPage = savedState.currentPage;
        mSnapPage = savedState.currentPage;
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        SavedState savedState = new SavedState(superState);
        savedState.currentPage = mCurrentPage;
        return savedState;
    }

    static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
        int currentPage;

        public SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        private SavedState(Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            currentPage = in.readInt();
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
            dest.writeInt(currentPage);
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
            @Override
            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new SavedState(in);
            }

            @Override
            public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }
        };
    }
}
```